# UITabBarController don't autosize UITabBarItem

Tags: ios

[image: UITabBar]

I'm a new iOS learner, but when I follow a tutorial, I met this problems. In tutorial, if I have two Tab Bar Item like I did, there will be two button on Tab Bar with width equal to 50% Tab Bar width. But actually all my Tab Bar Item get 100% size.

So what can I do to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a very nice tutorial via this link (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2099944?start=0&tstart=0).

You should implement the UITabBarDelegate protocol documentation here:(https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Once you are implementing this protocol, just use the - (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item method to know when a user changes the selected item of a tab bar. In this method's implementation, you will have to check which item is selected, and manually change your view's content based on that.

Hope this will help you in this issue.

Comment: Check this one too : http://cocoadiary.wordpress.com/2013/01/28/ios-tutorialhow-to-use-uitabbar/  may it will help you.

Comment: Please dont provide only link answers.

Comment: Yeah, good tutorial. But I can't fix problems when I create an empty user interface and added UITabBarController after that. It's still full width. Can I change UITabBarItem size, or at least, make it autosize as it should ?

Comment: Yes, I check your scenario you are right there is some kind of bug I guess from Apple.But you can select Tabbar Project from the start instead of select empty project and your problem will be resolve. And I suggest to use storyboard instead of .xib file.

Answer (score 0):

TabBar icon should have a size of 30*30 pixel for non-retina and 60*60 for retina display.

While using these image just use the name. If you have a image named **tab_image** then you should add 2 image for that.

```
tab_image.png (30*30 pixels)
tab_image@2x.png (60*60 pixels)
```

And while using the image just write:

```
self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_image"];
```

iOS will determine whether to use the 30*30, or 60*60 image. Hope this helps .. :)